# How to get local codepage in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

In Windows, I can use `GetAPC` function to get the local codepage.

But how should I do to get local codepage in Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean GetACP ?? code page identifier for OS ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux does not use code page identifiers. It has [locale](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html) identifiers, but different processes can have different locales and a process may be using different locales in [different categories](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html) at once. Every C program starts off in the "[C](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Locales.html)" locale, but can easily set [change to locales specified by the environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html). Note that [locale names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html) can vary between systems.

Comment: Ohh I think Linux is similar with Windows. Now I know, thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not have a single code page. Instead, it has a [locale](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html) system. The locale entry that most resembles Windows' ACP is the `LC_CTYPE` field. Please note that `LC_ALL` is used instead, if it's defined. Also, if `LC_CTYPE` isn't defined (and it rarely is), `LANG` is used instead.

With that said, I need to ask you why you think you need it. In almost any modern Linux OS, the "codepage" is UTF-8. It might have lots of different names, but it's still usually UTF-8.

Comment: Because I think Linux will has different "code page" like Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a `GetAPC` command in Windows nor elsewhere, but perhaps what you were looking for is the `locale` command:

> ```
> Usage: locale [OPTION...] NAME
>   or:  locale [OPTION...] [-a|-m]
> Get locale-specific information.
>
>  System information:
>   -a, --all-locales          Write names of available locales
>   -m, --charmaps             Write names of available charmaps
>
>  Modify output format:
>   -c, --category-name        Write names of selected categories
>   -k, --keyword-name         Write names of selected keywords
>   -v, --verbose              Print more information
>
>   -?, --help                 Give this help list
>       --usage                Give a short usage message
>   -V, --version              Print program version
> ```

### See Also:

- archlinux.org : [`locale`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale)
- man7.org : [`locale`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html)

Comment: >>> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getacp   :-)